# Configuring log levels in log5j

Tags: log5j

Is there an easy/good way to configure class specific or package specific log levels in [log5j](http://code.google.com/p/log5j/)? The google code project page seems to have almost no documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the documentation is almost nonexistent but it seems to me that this is a new API that still uses Log4j behind, therefore the configuration would still be through `log4j.properties` or `log4j.xml`.